# Subtract time from sql time column

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, where-clause

I am trying to write a query that detect when a reservation is in the last 15 mins of it (so it knows it's nearly done). So as of now I have:

`UPDATE bookings b JOIN reservation_time_data r ON r.id = b.reservation_time SET b.reservation_processed = 'ending' WHERE reservation_date LIKE ? AND CURRENT_TIME BETWEEN(r.end_time AND r.end_time - '00:15:00.000000')`

Usually for adding time I would use `ADDTIME()` but for this I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could phrase this as:

```
where 
    reservation_date like ? 
    and r.end_time between current_time - interval 15 minute and current_time
```